# Iterative approximate solutions to games

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

Suppose you and I are playing a two-player zero-sum game repeatedly. There is a payoff matrix $(A_{ij})$, and if I play action $i$ and you play action $j$ then I receive $A_{ij}$ and you receive $-A_{ij}$. I am not clever enough to compute my best strategy (my maximin strategy), but I can just manage to compute a best response to your mixed strategy, if you were to publicize it. Similarly you. We decide that at each turn (i.e., repetition of the game) we will just play a best response to our opponent's apparent strategy so far. To be more specific we each do the following:

- Turn $1$: Play something. Who cares. It's only one turn.
- Turn $n$: Play a best response assuming that the opponent will simply pick one of turns $1,\dots,n-1$ uniformly at random and replay that action.

This is an attractive rough and ready way to try to solve a two-player game when tackling the linear program head-on is difficult. But is it any good? That is, do our strategies converge to our respective maximin strategies? Williams's *Compleat Strategyst* says it works, but unfortunately it's not the sort of book that gives references.

For example, if we were playing rock-paper-scissors, the play might go as follows:

- rock, rock (we both start arbitrarily)
- paper, paper (paper is the best response to rock)
- paper, paper (paper is the best response to 1/2 rock, 1/2 paper)
- scissors, scissors (scissors is the best response to 1/3 rock, 2/3 paper)
- etc.

Clearly play is always symmetric here and we always draw, but that is not important (and wouldn't be true if we started with different actions). The only thing I care about is whether our distribution of actions converges to 1/3 rock, 1/3 paper, 1/3 scissors (the optimal strategy), and how fast.

Comment: Can you give more details? What exactly is your definition of a game? What is a turn? What are the winning conditions? What is the pay-off? In its current state you can easily construct a 'game' in which this approach will fall flat. Simply let a given player lose if he follows your proposed strategy.

Comment: @Stefan The game is an arbitrary zero-sum two-player game with an arbitrary payoff. The turns are repetitions of the game. We are trying to find our maximin strategies, i.e., the Nash equilibrium. I added some more words to try to make this clear.

Comment: I see. Your kind of games look pretty different from the ones I had in mind. Thanks for your clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keywords I was looking for were "fictitious play" and "Brown--Robinson process". The short answer seems to be that it works, sometimes. For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_play.